# Polling Laravel Queue after All Jobs are Complete

Tags: php, laravel, queue

Are there any best practices for identifying when jobs/workers finish processing a Laravel queue?  The only approach I can think of is to poll the jobs table to see when there are no more jobs in the queue.

The challenge I have is that I'll periodically dispatch 1,000 jobs to the queue and then some time later another 1,000 and then another.  I'd like to be able to trigger an event once each batch of jobs is complete, if possible.

Thanks for any suggestions or pointers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no such functionality. However, it's simple to implement by listening for the `Illuminate\Queue\Events\Looping` event (was `illuminate.queue.looping` before Laravel 5.4) and check the queue size.

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Contracts\Events\Dispatcher;
use Illuminate\Queue\Events\Looping;

class QueueSizeCheckerAndEventThingieSubscriber {

    public function subscribe(Dispatcher $events) {
        $events->listen(Looping::class, self::class . '@onQueueLoop'); // >= 5.4
        $events->listen('illuminate.queue.looping', self::class . '@onQueueLoop'); // < 5.4
    }

    public function onQueueLoop() {
        $queueName = 'my-queue';
        $queueSize = Queue::size($queueName);

        if ($queueSize === 0) {
            // Trigger your event.
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: i am interested by your approach .I tried to implement such subscriber for my redis queue but I always receive Queue:size == 0 and even when i know the jobs are still in processing so the queue cannot be empty. Your Queue::size is a use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Queue?...thks for feedback

Comment: @mg3 That sounds hard to debug without access to your system. I would check if you're checking the correct queue, and if there's pending jobs in it. I'm not sure if all queue drivers include currently executing jobs into the size value.

Comment: When implementing this solution, you might want to add `namespace App\Listeners;` and `use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Queue;` to the file as well. Finally, don't forget to register the subscriber in `$subscribe` inside `App/Providers/EventServiceProvider.php` as per the documentation: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/events#registering-event-subscribers

Comment: Also, once the queue has finished processing its jobs and is empty, the `// Trigger your event` part of the above code will keep firing. It won't just trigger once.

Answer (score 0):

I think preventOverlapping will be best suited for your need.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/scheduling#preventing-task-overlaps

I am already using it with jobs with beanstalkd and supervisor running fine. Never had an issue till

Answer (score 0):

kregus comment is very true on the accepted answer

"once the queue has finished processing its jobs and is empty, the //Trigger your event part of the above code will keep firing. It won't just trigger once"

To trigger the event once use that. In the EventServiceProvider

```
public function boot()
{

    Queue::after(function (JobProcessed $event) {
        if(Queue::size($queueName)==0){
         //trigger your event
         }
    });
    }
```