# Run function once when all Laravel jobs in queue are finished

Tags: laravel, queue, jobs

My Laravel web app analyzes thousands of stocks each day.

After it has analyzed all stocks individually, I need to run a function *once* that generates some stats about the stock market as a whole, and sends out an email with the results to my users.

Because of the amount of data that needs to be crunched per stock, I had to use a Laravel job per stock, or else the script would time out, and I need to run them async with multiple workers, or else the analyses won't be finished before the next trading day starts.

My question: **how can I fire a function once when all jobs in the queue are finished?**

I was thinking about scheduling a task that fires daily when `Queue::size() === 0`, using something like:

```
$schedule->call('App\Http\Controllers\DataController@runFinalFunctions')->daily()->when(function () { 
      // Check if job queue has finished running
      if (Queue::size() === 0) {
          // Queue empty or finished
          return true;
      }
});
```

But how to know the difference between a queue that is empty because the jobs haven't started yet, and a queue that is empty because all jobs for that day have finished running?

Ideally I would not have a CRON job that keeps polling, but rather a callback that fires just once when the queue goes from having jobs to having no jobs.

Any idea how to achieve this elegantly? I would be forever in your debt :-)

Comment: What about using job chaining? https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queues#job-chaining

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41228745/polling-laravel-queue-after-all-jobs-are-complete

Comment: @EdwinKrause That allows me to run a job after a single stock has been analyzed, but not after *all* stocks have been analyzed.

@levi Thanks for that link! Never heard of the `Looping` event before, and can't seem to find any documentation on it, but I'll give it a go.

Comment: @levi I implemented that solution, and it turns out that the trigger will be fired indefinitely as long as the queue is empty, so it does not solve my issue of only firing a function **once** when the queue is finished.