# Laravel Queue. Execute a function when the queue becomes empty

Tags: php, laravel, queue, jobs

I have a queue. After completing all the tasks, I would like to execute the function. Example

Queue:
Task1
Task2
Task3
Task4
Task5

Here, when queue is empty, we have to run Function.
The documentation only has an event that fires after every task.

Comment: The queue is not designed to work in such a manner, theoretically the queue can be full for a long time if multiple jobs queue up. If you have database rows associated with it an flag like is_done and an event to check if all the associated rows has been ranned is the correct approach in my opinion.

Comment: @mrhn I am importing data via a queue, then I need to sort it

Comment: @mrhn I found this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41228745/polling-laravel-queue-after-all-jobs-are-complete

Answer (score 1):

Hey Alex you could work with Livewire and request all 3 sec if the table jobs is empty. when the table is empty you can then fire a function.

Livewire Controller:

```
public string $filename;
public mixed $errorlist = [];
public bool $showLoadSequence = True;

public function getError()
{
    // check if job table is empy
    if (!DB::table('jobs')->exists() && $this->showLoadSequence === True) {
        $this->showLoadSequence = False;
        // call to action!
    }

    $errors = ValidationResult::where('file_name', '=', $this->filename)
        ->where('isValid', false)
        ->get();

    if (count($errors) !== count($this->errorlist)) {
        $this->errorlist = $errors;
    }
}

public function render()
{
    return view('livewire.error-loader');
}
```

Live wire blade:

```
<div wire:poll.3s="getError">
 //html tags
</div>
```